# Finder always opens 1 folder behind

Tags: macos, finder

Ever since the latest update of MacOS `10.15.4`, `Finder` seems to open one folder behind where it is supposed to.

For example, in `Xcode`'s Preferences->Locations, I click the arrow to take me to the Derived Data folder, it opens `Finder` at the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/` folder and not the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` folder like it used to.

The same happens when I uncompress something and have it set to open the uncompressed folder in a new window. It opens 1 folder behind the actual folder.

This only started happening after the latest MacOS update.

Does anyone else have the same issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I had a different problem which I solved by deleting the Finder preferences using `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` and relaunching Finder. It’s a bit drastic, but sometimes necessary.

Comment: No I didn’t. I still have the issue. It also happens on a brand new MacBook, so doubt it’s a preference issue.